# IntelliJ Plugin - Run Console Command

Tags: java, intellij-idea, console, intellij-plugin

I am new to plugin development for IntelliJ and would like to know, how I can execute a command in the command line from within my plugin.

I would like to call, for instance, the command "gulp" in the current projects root directory.

I already tried using

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);
```

with commands like "cd C:\Users\User\MyProject" and "gulp", but it does not seem to work that way and I wonder, if the plugin API provides an easier method.

Comment: Do you want to call `gulp` from your Java program, or are you asking about something else?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen He's asking from within a plugin for the IDE Idea

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know its a bit late (1 year later), but recently I was working on an IntelliJ plugin and I had the same issue and this is what I used and it works pretty well.

First, we need to create a list of commands that we need to execute:

```
  ArrayList<String> cmds = new ArrayList<>();
  cmds.add("./gradlew");
```

Then

```
  GeneralCommandLine generalCommandLine = new GeneralCommandLine(cmds);
  generalCommandLine.setCharset(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
  generalCommandLine.setWorkDirectory(project.getBasePath());

  ProcessHandler processHandler = new OSProcessHandler(generalCommandLine);
  processHandler.startNotify();
```

hence the `generalCommandLine.setWorkDirectory` is set to the project directory which could be equivalent to the terminal command `cd path/to/dir/`

Comment: Hi, I'm also implementing an intelliJ plugin that runs cmd commands. 
I tried using your code and I get an error of "Cannot run program ".\gradlew" in directory [project directory]: The system cannot find the file specified" (of course it can;t find it there, the project's dir isn't the plugin's dir...). Can you help me please?

Comment: If you're just trying to run something and get its output `ScriptRunnerUtil.getProcessOutput(generalCommandLine)` works really well

Answer (score 0):

The Runtime class provides **exec(String[], String[], File)** method where the last argument is working directory of the subprocess being launched.

The plugin API provides **OSProcessHandler** class (as well as other classes like **ProcessAdapter**) which can help to manage the subprocess, handle its output etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ProcessOutput result1 = ExecUtil.execAndGetOutput(generalCommandLine);
```

`result1.getStdOut` `result1.getStdErr` works

and

```
ScriptRunnerUtil.getProcessOutput(generalCommandLine, ScriptRunnerUtil.STDOUT_OUTPUT_KEY_FILTER, timeout);
```

both work pretty well
and they are built into intellij

```
import com.intellij.execution.process.ScriptRunnerUtil;
import com.intellij.execution.util.ExecUtil;
```